# DateFormatter not actually checking date format

Tags: ios, format, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to check if user types a date in a certain format. I get this input from a `UITextField` and then I try to validate this way:

```
func checkDateInput(inputStr: String) -> Bool {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: inputStr) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Before calling this method, I check that `inputStr` is not empty.
When I run the app and I type, for instance, "12/07/2016", I get a `true` as a result of `checkDateInput(inputStr: "12/07/2016")`, but I expected to get a `false` because I want the user to type "12-07-2016". It looks like `DateFormatter` is not considering "-" and "/" different characters in the format I provide.

How could I achieve an exact match to the format of a date?

Comment: It returns true because DateFormatter is still capable of formatting that wrong input. If all you need is the correct string, just call dateFormatter.string(from: date) to get the correct string. If checking is more important, you will have to use either regex which I am not familiar with enough to help you or check using the native String functions

Answer (score 0):

For Simple Solution you can check character at `2` , `5` position of your `inputStr` like this way

```
func checkDateInput(inputStr: String) -> Bool {

    let ch2 = inputStr[inputStr.index(inputStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)]
    let ch5 = inputStr[inputStr.index(inputStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)]

    if ch2 != "-" || ch5 != "-" {
        return false
    }

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"

    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: inputStr) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```